# Virtual keyboard for Libertine

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, tablet, aquaris, libertine

Working with Libertine Desktop Apps (without real keyboard and mouse) on Aquaris tablet needs a good virtual keyboard with arrows, `PgUp`, `Tab`, `Ctrl` (or even virtual mouse), that can be always on top. It will be great to use virtual keyboard from Terminal App with any Libertine Desktop App! But maybe, anybody has experience to use Florence or Onboard virtual keyboard with Libertine? Or some other keyboard? Which one be suitable?

Comment: Have you tried the matchbox keyboard? It's integrated in the Libertine Container and can be runned by this command: DISPLAY=:0 libertine-container-manager exec -c matchbox-keyboard

Comment: Thank you, Bjarne! I can start it only via  `DISPLAY=:0 libertine-launch my-container matchbox-keyboard`. It's interesting now how to configure this keyboard?

Comment: It can work via `libertine-container-manager exec -c matchbox-keyboard`, too. Merely it needs to start target app before matchbox-keyboard. I found config files in `~/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs/usr/share/matchbox-keyboard`

Comment: You must edit the keyboard.xml file. Ugly but that's the most direct way.

Comment: interesting use case. FYI the matchbox-keyboard package will no longer be installed by default in containers in the next release, so it will have to be installed manually.

Comment: Full layout for most cases isn't necessary, but matchbox-keyboard hasn't a height attribute (to change total height of keyboard). Perhaps, it will be more preferable to compile [this fork](https://github.com/xlab/matchbox-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Let me combine comments and some piece of info from Internet and write answer. Matchbox-keyboard configuration is buggy, but it was possible to create a suitable config file only with arrows, some navigation keys and small height. [Example of configuration see there](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23361329/). Place it in file

```
~/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs/home/phablet/.matchbox/keyboard.xml
```

Screenshot of usage:

[image]

At first we should start app (like Evince or Firfox), where we want to use navigation arrows. After that we should run matchbox-keyboard from terminal as Bjarne described:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 libertine-container-manager exec -c "matchbox-keyboard" --id my-container
```

Right now I don't know how to create single launch file (.desktop) to run the matchbox-keyboard. And only one window with matchbox-keyboard is supported now.

Comment: If we copy config file: ``cp ~/.cache/libertine-container/my-container/rootfs/home/phablet/.matchbox/keyboard.xml ~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/my-container/.matchbox/keyboard.xml``, then we can use ``DISPLAY=:0 libertine-launch my-container matchbox-keyboard``

Comment: Desktop Mode should be used for stable work of matchbox-keyboard.

Comment: I found description of such bug on launchpad: [Add on-screen-keyboard support for Xmir/Libertine apps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-pocket-desktop/+bug/1543351). I think, it was in previous OTA. Let it be there for history.